# Generate unified report from more than one maven junit tests output execution

Tags: maven, logging, junit, reporting

I have a parameterized junit test suite that i run with maven, with the following command in Jenkins:

```
export SUITECONF=SuiteConfig*

for f in src/test/resources/$SUITECONF ; \
do export SUITECONF=$(basename "$f" | cut -d. -f1) && \
mvn test -Dtest=TestSuite#testCase -q 2>/dev/null; \
done
```

that expands the SuiteConfig* filename in "src/test/resources/SuiteConfig*" and did like the following:

```
export SUITE_CONF=suiteconf1
mvn test -Dtest=TestSuite#testCase -q 2>/dev/null
export SUITE_CONF=suiteconf2
mvn test -Dtest=TestSuite#testCase -q 2>/dev/null
export SUITE_CONF=suiteconfN
mvn test -Dtest=TestSuite#testCase -q 2>/dev/null
...
```

But the output file "target/surefire-reports/com.package.suites.TestSuite.txt" that has the output of the execution gets overwrited with every mvn command, so i need a way to have the output to be like if all the tests where executed on the same run.

The quick workaround I found is to use a try/catch and to print the test pass/failed to the System.out and was thinking to parse the output with the Jenkins "Log Parser Plugin".

```
    @Test
    public void testCase() {
        try {
            // Test config
            ...

            // Test data
            ...

            // Test case
            ... 

            System.out.println(operator + "#" + testName + " <<< TEST PASS");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(operator + "#" + testName + " <<< TEST FAILED");
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw (e);
        }
    }
```

but want to know if there's a better way to do all this. Maybe that i can have an output like:

```
TestConfig1#testCase1 <<< TEST PASS
TestConfig1#testCase2 <<< TEST PASS
TestConfig1#testCaseN <<< TEST PASS
TestConfig2#testCase1 <<< TEST PASS
TestConfig2#testCase2 <<< TEST PASS
TestConfig2#testCaseN <<< TEST PASS
TestConfigN#testCase1 <<< TEST FAILED
TestConfigN#testCase2 <<< TEST FAILED
TestConfigN#testCaseN <<< TEST FAILED
```

Thanks in advance